# Fix plaster behind skirting board

Tags: plaster, skirting

I'm renovating an old house circa 1893, and I have a problem with blown plaster behind a skirting board.

I'd like to leave the skirting board undamaged as its an origin feature, but how can I repair the plaster behind it?

Is my only option to remove the whole skirting board and re-plaster?  The rest of the plaster on the wall is fine so I'm hoping there's a way to avoid replacing the whole lot.

Thanks

[image: Blown plaster]

Comment: The _best_ option is to temporarily remove the baseboard. You could work around it, but you'll have a seam showing at the top and it'll be a hassle. What's the problem with removing the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand not wanting to risk damaging that original trim, but it appears the piece is only a few inches long and not solidly attached. It's probably easiest to carefully remove it, use plaster and/or drywall to fill in the area behind, then reattach the short piece of trim.  If you damage it slightly, you can fill dents and cracks with wood putty, then just sand and paint.

Comment: It doesn't look like a short piece, it looks like a feature was there, such as a window seat... painted up to for a while, then the whole place was allowed to deteriorate a bit. The layer of undisturbed dust, just makes it look that way.